# Estrutura banco de dados Mysql

Tags: mysql, der

Olá
Estou precisando de uma forcinha para estruturar meus dados em um banco de dados.

Tenho uma tabela para procedimentos de exames com id, nome do exame e valor.
Só que o problema é que um "procedimento" pode conter outros procedimentos, e nesse caso o valor unitário de cada procedimento muda.

Exemplo - Procedimentos avulsos
-Radiografia 10.00
-Fotografia 5.00
-Slide 15.00
-Modelo 50.00

Exemplo de Grupo de procedimentos
-Documentação A
--Radiografia 8.00
--Fotografias 3.50
--Modelo 40.00

-Documentacao B
--Radiografia 8.00
--Fotografias 2.50
--Modelo 40.00

Só que estes procedimentos das documentações precisam referenciar o id dos procedimentos avulsos.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia montar um *schema* dessa forma:

**Tabela: Procedimentos**

```
id (auto-increment)  
procedimentos (Fotografia, Slide, etc)
valor (1.00, 2.00, etc)
```

**Tabela: Grupo de procedimentos**

```
id (auto-increment)
grupo (Documentação A, Documentação B)
```

**Tabela: Procedimentos-Grupo**

```
id_procedimentos (id da tb procedimentos)
id_grupo (id da tb grupo)
valor (Inserir o valor diferenciado)
```

Buscando pela tabela **Procedimentos-Grupo** você consegue obter os valores individuais ou diferenciados, além de poder dar um `GROUP BY` em `id_grupo`, para mostrar seus grupos.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se a resposta lhe atendeu satisfatoriamente, clique na seta superior a esquerda para me pontuar. Qualquer dúvida, estou a disposição.

Comment: Estou com aviso dos 15 pontos. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.